# Vincenty through a list o list

Tags: python-3.x, geopy

Hello I want to use vincenty from geopy.distance to calculate the distance from a list of list of coordinates.

This is my code:

```
import geopy 
from geopy.distance import vincenty
x = [[45.4777928, 9.1607807], [45.4625482, 9.1443695], [45.4632698, 9.1977634]]
vincenty(x)
```

The output error is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: From the [docs](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance) I see that you usually give 2 arguments instead of 3 you provided. Nonetheless your list is a single argument and should be unpacked using `vincentry(*x)`.

Comment: Thank you @zipa! Now it works

Comment: Funny enough I don't have `geopy` installed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment (don't have `geopy` myself) you need to unpack the list into arguments using:

```
vincentry(*x)
```